# Check presence of a nested attribute with scan in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I want to scan items from DynamoDB which contain a certain attribute in a nested map structure.

For example, my item is:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "map1": {
        "Random1": {
            "X": 5,
            "Y": 6
        },
        "Random2": {
            "Z": 7,
            "Y": 8
        }
    }
}
```

where `Random1` and `Random2` are random strings. Now I want all the items that have `X` as the key in such such a nested structure.

I tried this:
`aws dynamodb scan --table-name dummy --profile dummy --region us-east-1 --filter-expression "attribute_exists(map1.*.X)"` but it doesn't work as wildcards don't work in DynamoDB. How else can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly noted, you can't perform this type of operation in DynamoDB.  Wildcard queries are not the sweet spot for DynamoDB.

You can either do this sort of filtering in your application code, or you can reorganize the way you store your data to support this access pattern.  There is no DynamoDB operation (e.g. `query` or `scan`) that will allow you to perform this type of search.